# How do you remove defaul GWT style from CaptionPanel widget?

Tags: css, gwt, gwt2, uibinder

How do you remove defaul GWT style from CaptionPanel widget ?

In my .ui.xml I tried pretty much everything. I tried setting `stylePrimaryName` and `styleName` to my classname. I also tried defining `.gwt-CaptionPanel` with no effect.

My .xml looks something like this:

```
<ui:style src="../common.css">
    .test {
        color: red;
    }

    .gwt-CaptionPanel {

    }
</ui:style>

<g:CaptionPanel captionText="Test" stylePrimaryName="{style.test}">
</g:CaptionPanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CaptionPanel` does not have a default style defined, so `.gwt-CaptionPanel` that you think exists, actually is not used. `CaptionPanel` is implemented as a `<fieldset>` tag so there should be no problem with the color text, but since you are not putting anything inside the caption panel you will not actually see anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid issues for all controls you can open your AppName.gwt.xml and make sure you've commented out the default styles:

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/> 
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> 
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/>
```