# When working with canvas the window always seems to overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

As the title says im trying to work with canvas but whenever i try to set its height and width to 100% height and width of the page it just overflows by a tiny bit. I have no clue why its happening and its very annoying when trying to make something.

Does anyone have a clue as to why it is happening?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Canvas Practice</title>
   <style type="text/css">
    canvas{
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    html,body
    {
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;

    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="canvas.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my html with some basic inline css.

Comment: Please attach the example of your code.

Comment: Did you set the `body`’s `margin` to `0`?

Comment: Welcome to SO buddy. To get better answers, it helps to produce a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There may be multiple reasons for that. Please post your code along with the question to help us understand your scenario.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get rid of padding/margin around <canvas> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802788/get-rid-of-padding-margin-around-canvas-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add display: block; to your canvas and it will work. I have added background just for reference.

```css
    canvas{
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        background: #222;
    }
    html,body
    {
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;

    }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Canvas Practice</title>
   
</head>
<body>
    <canvas></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="canvas.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks man its finally starting to work. now i can move on to actually studying the canvas

Comment: Glad it helped. accept it as answer for others to get help as well.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is to always keep the canvas in its own div.

The only thing that will ever be in this div is the canvas.

Then you can use CSS to resize the div however you want. You want it as large as the body? Give the div width: 100%.

Then you can always rightfully do:

```
 canvas.width = theDiv.clientWidth;
canvas.height = theDiv.clientHeight;
```

Comment: just gave that a shot but for some reason the height still overflows by a tiny amount

Comment: Try using the CSS rule fixed for position with the canvas element:

position:fixed;
left:0;
top:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;

Comment: managed to get it to work by mashing css lines onto it for days. but tbh normally it works perfectly fine but this time it just didnt listen to its window size.