# How to make canvas width and height fit the parent element in Vuetify?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I still new in vue and vuetify, I wan to make `<canvas>` element to fit its parent element. Below is the App.vue file

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-toolbar app flat color="blue lighten-1">
      <v-toolbar-title>
        <span>VUETIFY</span>
      </v-toolbar-title>
    </v-toolbar>
    <v-content>
      <v-container fluid fill-height class="pa-0">
        <v-layout fill-height>
          <v-flex fill-height>
            <v-card tag="canvas"
                    color="black"
                    width="100%"
                    height="100%">
            </v-card>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
    <v-footer color="green lighten-1"></v-footer>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App"
};
</script>
```

and the result is like the image below

[image: canvas with style width and height 100%]

as you can see, the height is not fit the parent element, which make the page scrollable.

What make me more confuse, if i use `tag="div"` to make it a `<div>` tag, the width and height just like what i want.

```
    <v-card tag="div" // <= this tag
            color="black"
            width="100%"
            height="100%">
    </v-card>
```

below is the page with "div" tag

[image]

how to make the canvas fit? Is there something i doing wrong or miss?

here is the Codepen link
https://codepen.io/janucaria/pen/pYvGQb

thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802788/get-rid-of-padding-margin-around-canvas-element

Comment: @RoyJ no, the problem is not that