# How to Prevent GWT From Overriding CSS

Tags: css, gwt

My GWT application has a big `core.css` file that contains CSS for my entire application.

For the below HTML, I added CSS for the parent & child, as well as exclusively for the child. However, my CSS changes get overridden somehow. I am confident that these CSS changes are not getting overridden by my CSS since there's no other CSS for the parent or child.

```
<DIV class="parent">
   <DIV class="child">
   <Anchor ...>
</DIV>
```

Comment: Do you have spaces between class_=_"..." ? They shouldn't be there: class="..."

Comment: Since GWT generates the HTML, I don't believe that there are spaces between the classes. It was just my mistake in typing.

Comment: Are you familiar with the inspector eg. in webkit? You could inspect these 2 elements and see which css rules are applied and where they come from. http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/WebInspector

Comment: I agree with @WillemVanBockstal so hard that I have to add an extra useless comment to back him up! If you're writing CSS you should always use the web inspector, firebug, or equivalent to inspect your rules. (unless you are some sort of amazing CSS guru)

Comment: I've used Firebug and Chrome Developer Tools, however I believe that my question is particularly applicable to GWT. How can I ensure that my core.css CSS changes actually get used, and not overridden, at run-time?

Answer (score 0):

Overriding GWT style classes can be particularly painful. Review this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159739/override-gwt-styling) on how to properly override GWT style classes.

Another, but highly discouraged, method would be to make *very* conservative use of the `!important` rule. This is generally considered bad practice, but sometimes it is necessary in GWT when you only want to override only a particular property of a single Widget.

You could also try setting the style properties in code.

```
widget.getElement().setAttribute("backgroundColor", "red");
```

Note, GWT requires using camel case for the property names.