# GXT: BorderLayout style split bar

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

How can I style the split bar?
I want to apply a different color for the split bar of a border layout.
I'm using gxt-3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you could look at this CSS rules:

```
.x-layout-split { ... }
.ext-strict .ext-ie6 .x-layout-split { ... }
.x-layout-split-h { ... }
.x-layout-split-v { ... }
.x-layout-split-west .x-layout-mini { ... }
.x-layout-split-east .x-layout-mini { ... }
.x-layout-split-north .x-layout-mini { ... }
.x-layout-split-south .x-layout-mini { ... }
```

---

[updated]

One of the options is add your own styles and override the defaults rules.

```
SplitLayoutPanel splitLayoutPanel = new SplitLayoutPanel();
splitLayoutPanel.setStyleName("x-layout-split-v-override", true);
```

In the CSS file, add:

```
.x-layout-split-v-override.x-layout-split-v-override {
   ...
}
```

And so on.

Another option: write your interface that extends `ClientBundle`, for example:

```
public interface CommonCssBundle extends ClientBundle {
    public static final CommonCssBundle INSTANCE = GWT.create(CommonCssBundle.class);

    @Source("path/to/your/css/file/here/split-css-override.css")
    public CssResource css();
}
```

In the entry point make this call:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    ...
    CommonCssBundle.INSTANCE.css().ensureInjected();
    ...
}
```

Note, that you can always find out the names of the CSS rules by using Google Chrome or Firefox with Firebug.

What yet - highly recommend reading this topic: [**Override GWT Styling**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159739/override-gwt-styling)

Comment: I'm sorry but I am a newbie regarding gxt and gwt in general. Where are these rules located. The name of the file I mean. Upvoted for now. I will accept as soon as I test it.

Comment: Your answer helped a lot. Thank you and of course accepted. Have fun.